# Simple POSTGRESQL SELECT query too slow

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that stores logs from an Electronic Invoicing System webservice, this is my SQL Structure

```
CREATE TABLE public.eis_transactions
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('eis_transactions_id_seq'::regclass),
    operation_type character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    sale_id integer,
    delivery_note_id integer,
    sale_credit_note_id integer,
    debit_note_id integer,
    cdc text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    transaction_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    response_code character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    response_description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    xml text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    response_xml text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    response_datetime timestamp without time zone,
    created timestamp without time zone,
    modified timestamp without time zone,
    user_id integer,
    async boolean DEFAULT false,
    url character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    final_xml text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT eis_transactions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT eis_transactions_debit_note_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (debit_note_id)
        REFERENCES public.debit_notes (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT eis_transactions_delivery_note_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (delivery_note_id)
        REFERENCES public.delivery_notes (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT eis_transactions_sale_credit_note_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sale_credit_note_id)
        REFERENCES public.sale_credit_notes (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT eis_transactions_sale_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sale_id)
        REFERENCES public.sales (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT eis_transactions_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.eis_transactions
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: eis_transactions_id_idx

-- DROP INDEX public.eis_transactions_id_idx;

CREATE INDEX eis_transactions_id_idx
    ON public.eis_transactions USING btree
    (id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: eis_transactions_id_idx1

-- DROP INDEX public.eis_transactions_id_idx1;

CREATE INDEX eis_transactions_id_idx1
    ON public.eis_transactions USING btree
    (id ASC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: eis_transactions_id_idx2

-- DROP INDEX public.eis_transactions_id_idx2;

CREATE INDEX eis_transactions_id_idx2
    ON public.eis_transactions USING btree
    (id DESC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: eis_transactions_sale_id_delivery_note_id_sale_credit_note__idx

-- DROP INDEX public.eis_transactions_sale_id_delivery_note_id_sale_credit_note__idx;

CREATE INDEX eis_transactions_sale_id_delivery_note_id_sale_credit_note__idx
    ON public.eis_transactions USING btree
    (sale_id ASC NULLS LAST, delivery_note_id ASC NULLS LAST, sale_credit_note_id ASC NULLS LAST, debit_note_id ASC NULLS LAST, user_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Cointains ~800 rows, this is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM eis_transactions LIMIT 1000;
```

It takes more than 60 seconds to complete the query.

And this is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result i got:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM eis_transactions LIMIT 100;
Limit  (cost=0.00..15.94 rows=100 width=1108) (actual time=0.013..0.121 rows=100 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=15
  ->  Seq Scan on eis_transactions  (cost=0.00..128.03 rows=803 width=1108) (actual time=0.012..0.106 rows=100 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared read=15
Total runtime: 0.180 ms
```

But doing a `SELECT * FROM eis_transactions` (With or without `LIMIT`) will take more than 60 seconds. While i have other tables with more than 1000 and they don't take so long as this particular table.

What could be wrong ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you measuring the time at the client? What is the client? Your query shows `LIMIT 1000` and the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows `LIMIT 100`, which is the one you are concerned with? Add answers as update to your question. Since `Total runtime: 0.180 ms` I'm going to say this is a network and/or client issue.